# How to load PDF in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms app where I want to open a locally stored PDF. I don't need to load them within the app, I'm fine with shelling out to the device's default document viewer for PDFs. How can I do this?

I tried sending a WebView to the PDF, but that didn't work, I just got a blank page.

Answer (score 8):

I've recently done this in my own project using a custom renderer.  First implement an empty Xamarin forms view such as (I've included a bindable FilePath attribute):

```
    public class PdfViewer : View
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty FilePathProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create<DocumentViewer, string>(p => p.FilePath, null);

    public string FilePath
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)this.GetValue(FilePathProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            this.SetValue(FilePathProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Then create an iOS Renderer that will be registered for this control.  This renderer can, as it is within an iOS project, use the [Quick Look Preview Controller](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to delegate to the built in iOS pdf viewer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PdfViewer), typeof(DocumentViewRenderer))]

public class DocumentViewRenderer 
        : ViewRenderer<PdfViewer, UIView>
{
    private QLPreviewController controller;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<DocumentViewer> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        this.controller = new QLPreviewController();
        this.controller.DataSource = new DocumentQLPreviewControllerDataSource(e.NewElement.FilePath);

        SetNativeControl(this.controller.View);
    }

    private class DocumentQLPreviewControllerDataSource : QLPreviewControllerDataSource 
    {
        private string fileName;
        public DocumentQLPreviewControllerDataSource(string fileName)
        {
            this.fileName = fileName;
        }

        public override int PreviewItemCount(QLPreviewController controller) 
        {
            return 1;
        }

        public override QLPreviewItem GetPreviewItem(QLPreviewController controller, int index)
        {
            var documents = NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath;
            var library = Path.Combine(documents, this.fileName);
            NSUrl url = NSUrl.FromFilename(library);

            return new QlItem(string.Empty, url);
        }

        private class QlItem : QLPreviewItem 
        { 
            public QlItem(string title, NSUrl uri) 
            { 
                this.ItemTitle = title; 
                this.ItemUrl = uri; 
            } 

            public override string ItemTitle { get; private set; }

            public override NSUrl ItemUrl { get; private set; }
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't compiled and run this as I've extracted it from my larger project but in general this should work.

Answer (score 6):

I had to do something and solve it using a DependencyService . You can use it to open the pdf depending on each platform

I show you an example of how to solve it on Android :

**IPdfCreator.cs**:

```
public interface IPdfCreator
    {
        void ShowPdfFile();
    }
```

**MainPage.cs:**

```
private void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DependencyService.Get<IPdfCreator>().ShowPdfFile();
}
```

**PdfCreatorAndroid.cs**

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(PdfCreatorAndroid))]
namespace Example.Droid.DependecyServices
{
    public class PdfCreatorAndroid : IPdfCreator
    {

        public void ShowPdfFile()
        {
            var fileLocation = "/sdcard/Template.pdf";
            var file = new File(fileLocation);

            if (!file.Exists())
                return;

            var intent = DisplayPdf(file);
            Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);
        }

        public Intent DisplayPdf(File file)
        {
            var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
            var filepath = Uri.FromFile(file);
            intent.SetDataAndType(filepath, "application/pdf");
            intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
            return intent;
        }
    }
}
```

Result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrwzt.png

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/LittleKing2020/Xamarin-MuPDF) there is a good project that uses **MuPDF Library** in xamarin . I've tested it and it works properly.

With **MuPDF** you can *zoom out* , *zoom in* and even *write some note on PDFs*.