# Open pdf and offices documents in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, pdf, ms-word, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm looking for a way to open pdf and offices files(execl, word and stuff) from within my xamarin forms project.

so far i only found native ways to do this. and it is true that you can only open files local on the device?

I been looking at the xamarin components store, the xamarin developer documents and here on SO, and the closest thing i got was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25328159/xamarin-forms-open-pdf)

Anyway, anything would be awesome. thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone else.

You could just code the native way to do this, an then invoke that. much faster then looking for a plugin