# Render PDF in Xamarin Forms from a Stream

Tags: pdf, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.uwp

I have been searching the web however I have come up empty so felt the need to ask. We want to render a `PDF` file on `iOS`, `Android` and `UWP` through `Xamarin Forms` and the **most important part**, from a `Stream`.

I have come across answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25569410/32348) however they just reinforce the notion of loading from a file or url.

We are not allowed to store the `PDF` files unencrypted on disk so the only 2 possible options I can see are to:

1. Find a viewer that can render from a `Stream`
2. Implement/expand a viewer that can render from a `Stream`

I haven't been able to find much based on these options so I am either hoping for someone to know of some framework or method of achieving this or at least some form of starting point library wise.

Comment: Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47747934/7254781).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While PDFTron was the only supplied answer I encountered great difficulty firstly getting any information from the company themselves in order to get costing information and secondly the trial downloads and samples wouldn't even compile.

I actually did some further research in to paid for solutions and found that [SyncFusion](https://www.syncfusion.com) offered a `PDF` viewer control that could also render from a `Stream`. They also provided answers to all my questions and got us up and running within less than a day.

Answer (score 1):

[PDFTron PDFNet SDK](http://www.pdftron.com) is available for all the listed platforms, and Xamarin, and supports opening and viewing a PDF from a stream (no disk access required).

https://www.pdftron.com/pdf-sdk/xamarin-library
https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/xamarin/guides

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was hoping for something without a paid for solution although I have requested a price to find out the cost.